# How to find the equation of the hyperboloid?

Tags: calculus, quadrics

[image]

How do I solve this? I know it's one sheet and I have its base formula here:

[image]

What/where is capital A, B, and Z in this equation? I have a and b but no idea the rest of the parts. How do I start?
Thank you.

This is what I got but it's wrong:

$\left(\frac{x}{10}\right)^2+\left(\frac{y}{4}\right)^2=\left(\frac{z}{\sqrt{7}}\right)^2+1$

Comment: From the figure you should understand that $A,B$ are the semi-axies of the ellipsis at height $Z=7$

Comment: @enzotib thanks, what do i do from there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write the equation
$$
\left(\frac{x}{10}\right)^2+\left(\frac{y}{4}\right)^2=\left(\frac{7}{c}\right)^2+1
$$
then divide everything by the RHS, so that the new RHS becomes $1.$
Now you have an ellipsis and you have to extract the semi-axes and put them equal to $20$ and $8,$ respectively.
$$
  \frac{x^2}{10^2\left[\left(\frac{7}{c}\right)^2+1\right]}+\frac{y^2}{4^2\left[\left(\frac{7}{c}\right)^2+1\right]}=1
$$
then
$$
  10^2\left[\left(\frac{7}{c}\right)^2+1\right]=A^2=20^2\\
  \left(\frac{7}{c}\right)^2+1=2^2\\
  \left(\frac{7}{c}\right)^2=3\\
  \left(\frac{c}{7}\right)^2=\frac{1}{3}\\
  c^2=\frac{7^2}{3}\\
  c=\pm\frac{7}{\sqrt{3}}\\
$$
where you can take the positive sign, because $c$ only appear squared in the final equation.
You obtain the same if you use $B$, so the equation is
$$
\left(\frac{x}{10}\right)^2+\left(\frac{y}{4}\right)^2=3\left(\frac{z}{7}\right)^2+1
$$

Comment: thank you very much!

Comment: hi, i still need help. my answer was + or - negative sqrt(7) but I'm not sure which One I should use. My answer is above^ I tried using sqrt(7) but it wasn't the right answwer

Comment: @DoctorReality I provided more details of calculations

Comment: thanks you so much!

Answer (score 1):

The illustration has given  semi- major/minor axes $(A,B)$ values at height of $Z=7$. You have to see it.

You can find the only remaining unknown $c$  by plugging in its value into the the equation of the elliptic hyperboloid of 1 sheet:

$$ \dfrac{A^2}{a^2}+ \dfrac{B^2}{b^2}=  \dfrac{7^2}{c^2} +1. $$

Comment: thank you! this helps me a lot

Comment: hi, i still need help. my answer was + or - negative sqrt(7) but I'm not sure which One I should use. My answer is above^ I tried using sqrt(7) but it wasn't the right answwer

Comment: The hyperboloid is symmetrical about plane $Z=0$. This is confirmed by the square on Z. We have them  both $\pm7$. If the drawing has shown positive Z for purpose of illustrating, you can be sure that negative Z is equally valid, you can take anyone value in a given situation.

Comment: the answer still ain't working when I use 7

Comment: What value did you obtain for $c$?

Comment: its my edit in my main question ^

Comment: i tried both negative and positive and I tried moving it back to the left side but everything is still wrong

Comment: Only tomorrow we can chat if you agree.

Comment: sorry what do you mean by that?

Comment: yes i'm fine to chat tommrow

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112939/discussion-between-narasimham-and-doctor-reality).